# What is the different between global max_connections and spring.hikari.maximumPoolSize?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have arround 20 microservices all using mysql, there is one database but each microservice has
its own schema so the urls for each microservice is different:

microservice 1

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/micro1_db
```

microservice 2

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/micro2_db
```

I'm not a DBA so when the whole application throw connections problem I've simply apply
the following command on the mysql:

```
set global max_connections = 400; (the default is 150 I think).
```

Then after few months one microservice complains so I have configured the following for the specific microservice:

```
spring.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
```

The application is running locallaly with very few users, I need to know how to configure production ready. Is global connections is a must, if yes what will be the recomended size.
Is each microservice need "spring.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20", are this two configuration are
working together.
The application is not facebook scale but should allow 5 figure number simultaniously I presume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's `max_connections` is global for all schemas. MySQL Server has no distinction between different schemas or different clients for this purpose. The `max_connections` is the total for all schemas, all clients.

You should size `max_connections` at least as much as the *total* size of all connection pools that will connect concurrently. For example, if you have 20 microservices, each microservice consists of one Java process with one connection pool, and each pool is sized at 20, then the total would be 400.

I've supported some microservices that run multiple JVM processes, each with their own connection pool. Or the "microservice" consists of three or more instances for load-balancing and redundancy. These also create their own connection pools. And some services have "sidecar" processes that run background services, instead of solely request/response handlers. So the real total may be much higher.

---

Re your comments:

Typically an application that uses a connection pool, you can run many more threads than the size of the connection pool, because they share. That is, when the app needs to do a db transaction, it requests a connection from the pool, executes the transaction, and returns the connection back to the pool promptly.

In between db transactions, each thread may run other code that does not need a db connection. During this time, it should not hold onto a db connection.

If the threads hold onto db connections when they don't need them, then the pool will probably run out of available connections.

If your application threads really need db connections continuously, then you need to increase the pool size.

Every application is different with respect to how frequently it needs to use the db connection. I don't know your application, so I can't make any prediction about your best pool size.

Comment: I have microserices that running jobs, for those you recommend to increase the spring.hikari.maximumPoolSize to more than 20 ? to 100 for instance

Comment: There's no way for me to know that. It depends on how many concurrent threads you have using database connections at any given moment. If you get errors in your Java code like "no connection available" (or similar message), then you could be depleting the pool.

Comment: Well, 20K users can be logged in at once, each will use at least 1 transaction at once, which means 20K transactions I presume (for each microservice). In local is configure at 20 what will you recommend in production ?